# I cannot properly confugure nginx server on ubuntu

Tags: nginx, configuration, webserver

I'm learning how to configure a nginx server on linux mint Tessa.
Everything go fine on localhost.
When I try to run multiple server the problems start.
Here my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
#include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/servers.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

The servers.conf that I included

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.a.com;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/a/;
    }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.b.com;
        location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html/b/;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name "" localhost 127.0.0.1;
        return 404;
}
```

and my hosts file for local DNS

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1    tech.com
127.0.0.1 www.a.com 
127.0.0.1 www.b.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have two index.html file in /usr/share/nginx/html/a/ and /usr/share/nginx/html/b/, really basic

```
<h1>Welcome to a</h1>
```

and

```
<h1>Welcome to b</h1>
```

Everytime I use [www.a.com](http://www.a.com) or [www.b.com](http://www.b.com) the chrome browser send me to the localhost page, while firefox send me to the right page only for [www.b.com](http://www.b.com), while keep redirecting me for [www.a.com](http://www.a.com) to the localhost page.
What am I doing wrong????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok how stupid am I? The configuration was good, just my browser was caching the pages so it was giving me the cached page for localhost. I forced the page refresh whit ctrl f5 and everything works. Hopes this can helps some inattentive guys like me :))))